# How to see list of user using our zapier application?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have gone through all tabs like history, monitoring, version etc, but couldn't see user list in developer dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

If you've invited users to your application, you can see them in the `Visibility` tab. If your app is public, you can't see the list of Zapier users using it for security and privacy reasons.